# Editor function in Monobehaviour script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im writing a Unity3D script that loads AudioClips from a folder. I know how to make tools and editor extensions but now i am wondering if there is a way to get the script to show a button in its inspector window which for example would check how many audio clips there are in the folder and write the amount to the debug console?

Comment: Well, assuming that you already know the path to the folder, you could use Directory.GetFiles, loop over the resulting array, and check the extension to see if it's a valid AudioClip (.ogg, .mp3 etc). Count these, and Debug.Log the total.

Comment: Thanks! I do that already. I just want to learn how to adda  buttin in the inspector that would check it for me. Cause i always forget how the path should be specified. XD

Comment: Post some code with what you have, and I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/editor/adding-buttons-to-inspector) is a link to the official unity tutorial on adding a button to a custom inspector.

This explains that you can make a custom button using:

```
if(GUILayout.Button("Button Name Goes Here"))
{
    //Check for number of files here and then print to console.
}
```

in the `OnInspectorGUI()` method.

Edit: To answer the question on how to find the amount of files in a directory, you can use the `System.IO` namespace. The [`DirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class in this namespace takes a path as a string and will allow you to use it's [`GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss(v=vs.110).aspx) method to find all files in that directory. Please take the time to read over the documentation that I have linked here.

Comment: @Programmer I am unsure, pretty sure this answers the question. I think it might be that I only put the link to the tutorial at first. I didn't think it would be necessary to copy & paste the code from that there but apparently it was!

Comment: This is what i am trying at the moment. Youre answer is incorrect though. The OnInspectorGui needs to go in another class that inherits from Editor.

Comment: @Lautaro Yes i'm aware of that. I didn't think I would have to tell you that as it is in the link I posted. Are you wanting help with finding the directory? Or only finding how many files are in the directory? your question could be a wee bit more specific. :)

Comment: "The OnInspectorGui needs to go in another class that inherits from Editor"  What??  it's not meant to be a posting of a complete code solution; it's a perfect answer to the question.  That's just the class you need.

Comment: @Lautaro Check my edit, this tells you how to find all the files in a directory. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes its true. Thats in the link you posted. I was a bit to fast on the reading. Thanks!